# Custom script to convert values within the editor

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to write a custom VSCode script that would allow value conversion within the editor itself?

For example, in a `.css` file, I have the following content:

```
section {
  position: absolute:
  top: 114px;
  left: 72px;
}
```

I would like to easily convert the `px` values (`114px` and `72px`), into viewport width units (`vw`) for a `1200px` viewport.

Currently, I manually calculate `(114 * 100) / 1200` which gives me the `vw` value.

Does VSCode allow a way to transform `px` values into their corresponding `vw` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can write an extension to do this. Please see [our extension authoring documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview) for help getting started.

The basics idea would be something like:

```ts
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('do.convert', () => {
        const activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
        if (!activeEditor) 
            return;

        const range = activeEditor.document.getWordRangeAtPosition(activeEditor.selection.start, /a-z0-9%/i);
        const line = activeEditor.document.getText(range);
        const pxMatch = line.match(/(\d+)px/);
        if (!pxMatch)
            return;

        const px = + pxMatch[1];
        const edit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
        edit.replace(activeEditor.document.uri, range, `${(px * 100) / 1200}vw`);
        vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit);
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  How would this script be used?  From the documentation, it looks like this can only be invoked "when a specific file type is detected, when a specific file exists, or when a command is selected via the Command Palette or a key combination." Would I selected a text range, and then trigger via a key combo?

Comment: Yes, see the hello world extension for an example of registering a command: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world This command would be enabled in all files by default but you can also restrict it to just css files if you want. The example code gets the value from the cursor position but you can customize this to use the selection instead